# The bound for $p$-length of $p$-solvable group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite a $p$-solvable group, where $p$ is a prime number, (that is there is a normal series in $G$: $1=N_0<N_1<\ldots<N_r=G$ such that $N_i/N_{i-1}$ is a group of order not divisible by $p$ ($p'$-group) or $p$-group). The minimal number of factors in any such series, which are $p$-groups, is called **$p$-length** of $G$.

I try to show that $p$-lenth of $G$ is less or equal the nilpotence class of the Sylow subgroup $P$ of $G$. I will be grateful for the ideas and guidance.

Comment: Is this an exercise or a conjecture?

Comment: This is an exercise.

Comment: Hint: if $G$ is $p$-solvable with $O_{p^{\prime}}(G) =1$ then $O_{p}(G)$ contains its centralizer in $G$

Comment: I know about this fact (Hall-Higman  theorem)

Comment: Then that should be enough to answer the question (that result is only a Lemma towards the Hall-Higman theorem by the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further the hint: it follows from the fact mentioned in comments that for a general (finite) $p$-solvable group $G$ with Sylow $p$-subgroup $P \neq 1$, we have $Z(P) \subseteq O_{p^{\prime},p}(G)$ so that a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G/O_{p^{\prime},p}(G)$ has nilpotency class strictly smaller than that of $P$.